# C++ Multithreading - Thread safe code

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, thread-safety, critical-section

I'm working on a game engine that runs from a .dll. Inside, there is an exported function that returns a reference to a static class declared in it, like below:

```
__forceinline __declspec(dllexport) STATE* NF3DGetEngineState(void)
{
    static STATE s_State;
    return &s_State;
}
```

where `STATE` is a class that manages all components and has functions that accesses them via a critical section:

```
void Set(int val)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    ClassMember = val;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
}
```

where "CriticalSection" is a `CRITICAL_SECTION` member of the `STATE` class that is of course initialised. The context in which I use these functions is:

```
NF3DGetEngineState()->Set(10);
```

The question is: is this code thread safe?

From what I learnt, returning references to static declarations is not thread safe.

What can I do to make it so?

Comment: Please explain why you think it's not thread safe

Comment: I heard that returning references to static declarations is not thread safe? Am I right?

Comment: What are you doing with `ClassMember`? You need to use the same ressource protection while setting.

Comment: I return it in other get-type functions that contain, in quite the same manner, a critical section lock-release mechanism. The difference is that EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection are called in the constructor and destructor of a wrapper class that is always declared in that function.

Comment: The *first* call to NF3DGetEngineState() may not be thread-safe, depending on the compiler. But if you call it once in the main startup (before multiple threads try to access it), after that parallel calls will get the same instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which is your C++ version? If it is C++11 or later, than the code is as thread safe as it gets. If it is pre-11, it is unsafe with regards to first call to `NF3DGetEngineState`.

Clarification.

It is not that returning references to static variables 'is not thread safe'. On the contrary, it is 100% safe. What is not thread-safe pre-C++11 is static variable initialization itself. pre-C++11 makes no guarantees in regards to the concurrent calls to the function for the first time. In fact, all pre-11 C++ compilers I worked with would have a problem if you concurrently enter this function for the first time. The reason is, the code which compiler generates when static variables are used, looks approximately like following:

```
static bool static_var_initialized = false; 
if (!static_var_initialized) {
    new (&static_var) StaticVarType(); // Explicit constructor call
    static_var_initialized = true;
}
```

Obviously, there is a possibility of calling constructor multiple times if you happen to call this function multiple times before static variable is set to true.

In C++11, there is a guarantee that it will never happen, and constructor will be called only once. It also guarantees no threads will see unconstructed value.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your much needed help! :)